# Shallow copy by using Memberwiseclone() method

Tags: c#

```
class Test:ICloneable
{
    int a;

    Test()
    {  
        a = 20;
    }

    public int Data
    {
        set
        {
            a= value;
        }
    }

    object Clone()
    {
        this.MemeberWiseClone();
    }
}

Test a = new Test();
Test b = a;
```

Now, if we modify the data a, b also changes

Question 1:

When the assignment happens which function is called, is the `MemberwiseClone()` of the System.object called

Question 2:

```
Test a = new Test();
Test b = (Test) a.Clone();
```

If you change the data of a , b doesn't change, it is because of the shallow copy.

Does `MemberwiseClone()` creates new object and then does a copy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing `b = a` changes `b` to refer to the **same** object that `a` refers to.
Note that this is only true for classes; if `a` and `b` are structs, the value will be copied.

The `MemberwiseClone` method returns a new object and assigns all of the fields in the new object to refer to the values from the original object.
That's a shallow copy.

Comment: who is the resonsible for the creation of the new object? Because in the code i have just return this.MemeberWiseclone()

Comment: @Rag: `MemberwiseClone` creates a new object internally.

Comment: since the c# doesn't have assingment operator overloading, so when i assign a= b, which function will be called

Comment: @Rag: `a = b` translates into `stloc` or `stfld` (or other `st*`) opcodes.

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone.aspx):

> The MemberwiseClone method creates a
>   shallow copy by **creating a new object**,
>   and **then copying the nonstatic fields**
>   of the current object to the new
>   object. If a field is a value type, a
>   bit-by-bit copy of the field is
>   performed. If a field is a reference
>   type, the reference is copied but the
>   referred object is not; therefore, the
>   original object and its clone refer to
>   the same object.

`MemberwiseClone()` creates a shallow copy, this has nothing to do with the assignment you do here though:

```
Test a = new Test();
Test b = a;
```

Both object references (a and b) point to the *same* object now. If you need `MemberwiseClone()` you have to call it directly, just as you do in your `Clone()` method.